# How to change input type in orientdb

Tags: orientdb, orientdb-2.1

I have a class with name "employee" , in that class i have a property named "salary" with input data-type string. So, my question is can i change input data-type of "salary" from string to integer ? and if yes then how ?

Comment: You could use a javascript function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used this code to reproduce your problem

```
create class employee extends v
create property employee.salary string

insert into employee(salary) values ("1")
```

[image]

I used this query to changed the type of property salary

```
create property Employee.salary2 Integer
update employee set salary2=salary
DROP PROPERTY Employee.salary
update Employee remove salary
ALTER property Employee.salary2 name salary
update Employee remove salary2
```

[image]

Hope it helps

Comment: Is there any other approach ? Specially, the one where i do not have to create any extra property .

Comment: To my knowledge there isn't other approach

Answer (score 1):

In newer versions of OrientDB you can use `ALTER PROPERTY Employee.salary TYPE Integer`

Works for me on 2.1.19